# Beanstalk wont connect to RDS on the same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

So I have an RDS instance and an EB instance and when I try to connect to my RDS via my Beanstalk served app I get this error:

```
no pg_hba.conf entry for host "insert_host", user "user", database "database", no encryption
```

(obviously this is dummy data in the response but it gives out proper data)

What I'm certain of is that this RDS is in the same VPC as the EB, and that it contains the proper inbound rules for the EB, I've tried connecting to it locally and it works normally. I've even tried opening port 5432 to all ipv6 and ipv4 addresses and it still won't connect. Any ideas to what I might be missing ? I've also allowed all traffic from the EB's security group since I've seen that as a possible solution elsewhere ?

I've got the same setup (at least I think so) on another AWS account and it works like a charm so I'm wondering if anyone stumbled on this error before ? Also all the solutions to the error I found were focused around configuring pg_hba.conf which I'm pretty sure I can't access on RDS (maybe I'm wrong here ?)

Comment: This error means your username or password is incorrect most of the time.

Comment: It is connecting (the network connection is succeeding). However, the database username/password authentication is failing.

Comment: Hmm, I've triple checked the env values that are there and the values it puts in that log are good. I'm able to connect to it via DBeaver without issues ?

Answer (score 1):

So I don't know exactly why, but this worked out when I downgraded my RDS postgres engine to 14.7 from the latest version...

Answer (score 0):

RDS requires SSL for connections to Postgres by default starting with version 15: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL.Requiring